# Controling YouTube using keyboard with Samsung Dex

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts, samsung-dex

In the YouTube app using Samsung DeX, I can't figure how to use the keyboard to do things like turn the volume up/down, pause the video, and things like that.

It looks like the app is not configured to take input from the keyboard.

Is it possible to control YouTube using just only keyboard? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Looks like pressing Meta + ! (exclamation mark) will show a shortcut list? Have you tried it?

Comment: Tried, the shorcut list is about the system keymapping

Comment: What keyboard do you have?